# Odd anomaly with PHP and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with jQuery and PHP that I can't figure out. To understand, let me explain what I am doing.

I am making a small mobile web-app using jQuery Mobile for the UI and PHP for the server side. I have 95% of the app ready and on the last page I am having a problem.

The first page has three drop-down menus and a submit button. When the button is pressed, the info from the dropdown menus are transmitted via $_POST to the 2nd screen. Here, I verify that I have data and do some operations. If no data is send, I show an error. So far I hope everything makes sense.

Here is the code for the two pages:
Page 1: http://pastebin.com/N0bWdbv0
Page 2: http://pastebin.com/TpbHqGai

On the second page, in the browser I see this: Choose members:  (line 75)
BUT! if I look at the source of the page I don't see it anywhere, instead there is "Error! date" (line 65).

I honestly don't know why I get this inconsistency between what is show and what "View page source" displays.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile uses AJAX by default to navigate between pages in your site. So when you click a link to another page, you're still using the same DOM and bringing another pseudo-page into the DOM. This means that there are no actual page-loads that occur while navigating a jQuery Mobile website (by default) which in turn means that the source of the webpage does not change unless you refresh the page.

You can however see the "live DOM" by using some of the developer tools at your disposal (Chrome has a great set of DOM inspection tools).